# Is MongoDB's Index Alternative 1 or Alternative 2 or Alternative 3?

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing

Use the common definition that:

Alternative 1 Index = Index stores "Whole data record with key value k"

Alternative 2 Index = Index stores "<k, _id of a data record with search key value k>"

Alternative 3 Index = Index stores "<k, list of _ids of data records with search key value k>"

I checked the mongo index readme in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/, it looks like Alternative 2, but wanted to confirm.

Answer (score -1):

By default MongoDB creates a unique index on the _id field during the creation of a collection. You can see the default index (_id) and others you have created with the mongo Shell.

> db.collection.getIndexes() returns an array of documents that hold
> index information for the collection.

```
[
   {
      "v" : 2,
      "key" : {
         "_id" : 1
      },
      "name" : "_id_"
   },
 
  ...
]
```

- v: The version of the index.
- key: This is an unique index with the
  _id field in ascending order.
- name: The name of the index.

Comment: How do I know which alternative this index is though? Apparently the "version" here has nothing to do with it, it's just a way to measure how text are indexed. Ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#versions

Comment: Hi, you want to know, How MongoDB store the indexes?, and Could you explain what you mean by "key value k"?

Comment: Yes, I would like to know how Index are stored in the underlying of DB. "Key Value K" basically mean the indexed attribute as value K, thus being referred as "K".